# Content Provider syncing with multiple accounts

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-syncadapter

I have content provider, which syncs with a rest server using a sync adapter.

I would like to have an option to have multiple accounts attached to the content provider, each providing individual data.

When running my program it will ask the user which account to use and get the data from that account.

however What is the recommended way to setup the content provider to allow for the separation of data in the content provider?

I was thinking along the lines of using uris in the form 'content://authority/{account}/{table}', is the a better way to provide this separation?

Answer (score 0):

You can store an **Accounts table** in the database, then load desire account data properly. This likes ContactsProvider's implementation.